# How to make second .gitignore file work?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

So I have a github repo with a 2nd .gitignore file that doesn't seem to be working here:

https://github.com/WalnutiQ/WalnutiQ/blob/feature-issue_169/src/main/java/model/util/javaHeapTracker/.gitignore

This is the contents of the file:

```
heaptrace  
heaptrace.dat  
heaptrace.gclog
```

However when I am in the folder src/main/java/model/util/javaHeapTracker
and type `git status` I get the following:

```
# On branch feature-issue_169
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       heaptrace
#       heaptrace.dat
#       heaptrace.gclog
```

How do I change my .gitignore file to ignore these 3 files? My first .gitignore file is here: https://github.com/WalnutiQ/WalnutiQ/blob/master/.gitignore if that helps

Comment: I cloned your repo, and on the same branch, a file named "heaptrace" is ignored correctly. However, a file with trailing spaces ("heaptrace  ") is not ignored. Does your file have trailing spaces in the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `heaptrace*` in your .gitignore and it ignores all the files:

heaptrace
heaptrace.dat
heaptrace.gclog

even if heaptrace has trailing whitespaces you can't control